# move from one xterm and back again using wmctrl

Tags: xterm, wmctrl, fvwm

I'm running `fvwm` and have multiple virtual desktops open. I'd like to be able to write a bash script that would take me from one xterm to another---this part is easy, using `wmctrl -a` ---and then back again, which is the hard part.

I imagine that if I could execute a command in the new window once I've passed control to it, then the rest would be easy, but as far as I can tell from the documentation, wmctrl doesn't give me the option to do this.

Here's the basic idea of the script I'd like to write

```
#!/bin/bash
    TmpScreen=CAMILLE
    CurrScreen=ANDREW
    wmctrl -R   $TmpScreen
    #echo this line on CAMILLE not ANDREW
    echo "Type 'GoBack' to return to $CurrScreen" &
    #Do something on CAMILLE
    #Type GoBack, which would then execute
    wmctrl -a $CurrScreen
    #Be back to where I started
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?      Any help would be most appreciated

Comment: you should be able to get the current window id  with `xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW`, and so save it before moving to the new window.

Comment: Thanks @meuh,  I need something in addition though.    I need to be able to pass an echo command to the new window, i.e., starting in the Current window, i want to write an echo (containing information from your xprop command)  that shows up in the new window